# Chat links expose a pretty serious JavaScript exploit

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks, security

So I learned something rather surprising today and it's pretty scary. I'm actually stunned neither Chrome/Google, nor Mozilla, have plugged it. First, the logistics of how I ran across this

1. I linked to a page in chat (I want you to read this first so the link is at the end). Pretty benign site
2. Someone in chat clicked the link later.
3. That page then **hijacked the chat window and redirected it**

Now, what's cool is this site is trying to raise visibility of a pretty serious problem with JavaScript. I'd not heard of this before and it's quite the gaping security hole. As in this could do bad things right now.

> When a website uses `target="_blank"` on their links in order to open a new tab or window, that website gives the new page access to the existing window through the `window.opener` API, allowing it a few permissions. Some of these permissions are automatically negated by cross-domain restrictions, but window.location is fair game.
>
> In order to restrict this behavior, the original page needs to add a `rel="noopener"` attribute to any link that has `target="_blank"`. However, Firefox does not support that tag, so you should actually use `rel="noopener noreferrer"` for full coverage. I am not sure why this behavior even exists as the default, but it does. This is an extremely common vulnerability. If you landed on this page, I encourage you to contact the developers of the referring website and alert them of this issue.

You don't have to take my word for it tho. Here's how you can reproduce it on demand

1. Join any chat (chat links always open a new tab/window)
2. Paste this URL in and submit: https://dev.to/rly
3. Click the link in chat
4. It opens the link in a new tab/window **and** your chat window is redirected to https://dev.to/phishing

Looks like an easy fix (SO links already add `rel="nofollow"` for SEO purposes) but this needs fixing yesterday. Hat tip to [Kyll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/306392/kyll) for noting it does that.

Comment: For me it redirects only when clicked from transcript, not when I'm actually in the room. (tested [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1034/shadows-sandbox))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interesting. Was the opposite for me. It's starred in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and clicking the star link did it for me but not the transcript. Am using FF 49.0.1

Comment: Weird indeed. The chat link HTML source contains "noreferrer", while transcript does not, probably in other chat servers it's also different and not consistent.

Comment: This is a security vulnerability. You should not report this on Meta, ever. Use the contact form and choose 'Other', including the words Security Vulnerability. [Reference.](http://stackexchange.com/about/security) You should delete this post.

Comment: What I really want to know is, why the bloody hell do chat links open in new tabs when SE vehemently refuses to open all links in a new window when NOT in chat?  What is this, anarchy?

Comment: @Won't It's not anarchy, it's chat having a rebellion.

Comment: @Won't 100% of my links network-wide open in a new tab when I MMB-click

Comment: @TylerH the problem seems to be specific to `target="_blank"` links; I don't think it impacts MMB-click/ctrl-click/etc - you can test with the link above, though

Comment: @Won't - somehow related, why chat does one-boxing in the first place for content that could be compromised (even if the actual likelihood of that happening is very low)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A change has been deployed that ensures the  transcript (and other code that uses the particular code-path) adds the correct hints, and the hints have been extended to use all of them (although I am informed that `noreferrer` by itself would work)

Comment: It's not completely fixed yet; would you like me to explain here or somewhere more private like the "contact us" form?

Comment: @Nobody feel free to ping me at marc@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty alarming.

I noticed this only works when you click these links from the transcript or from the side bar, but not when clicking it directly from live chat.

Nonetheless, this should be fixed ASAP, as it allows some pretty serious griefing of chat users.