# Remind people posting about [security] that vulnerabilities shouldn't be posted on Meta

Tags: feature-request, tags, security

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286066/262823) was posted here on Meta today, detailing a security vulnerability in chat.

[stackexchange.com/about/security](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) says:

> Please *do not* post serious security issues publicly on a meta site or elsewhere.

That's not a very discoverable page - I had to Google to find it - so perhaps instead, we should have a tag popup for people who use the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag, reading something along the lines of

> If you believe you've found a security vulnerability, please use the [contact form](/contact) instead of posting it publicly on Meta.

Comment: Something [tag specific question requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286032/307988) could help with :)

Comment: @Cai that's exactly what I was thinking of

Answer (score 11):

I totally agree a message should be added. In the mean time I have added a small note to the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag excerpt, which will tell users to use the appropriate form.

It reads now:

> For posts about security issues centered around Stack Exchange. If you think you found a serious security vulnerability, please report it on the Security page found at https://stackexchange.com/about/security. Do not post such reports on Meta!

Feel free to alter the tag wiki or proposal in my answer.