# Why do external links use noreferrer?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

(This question is not about `nofollow`, which is something different.)

I've noticed that all external links are marked with the `noreferrer` attribute. The only discussions I can find of this on meta.SO and meta.SE are:

- [Chat links expose a pretty serious JavaScript exploit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286066), where it was suggested as a workaround for a security problem specific to the chat feature.
- [Archive.org URLs without asterisks not handled properly in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286411), where it was suggested as a workaround for a bug on archive.org.

However, I don't see any explicit statement that either of these were the actual reason for adding the attribute. Or was there another reason?

Removing referrer information does have a downside. By preventing website owners from discovering what questions they are linked from, we lose the opportunity of them visiting the question and contributing their expertise.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to tell you this, but referrer has never been a consistent source of information.

1. SO/SE is now fully served over HTTPS. So if you run a HTTP site, you'll get no referrer data from any browser, period ([per IETF standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2))
2. Many browser add-ons and even browsers themselves (in private modes) will hide the data
3. Other reasons listed in [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing)

The chat thing was about plugging the JS opener security hole. Firefox didn't properly support `noopener` [at the time](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1222516). But you can't rely on it being there.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that. But if the referrer is potentially useful both to the target site and to the SE site, shouldn't it be changed to `noopener` once that's widely enough supported? (The Firefox Bugzilla link says they supported it 16 months ago, but I appreciate that may not be enough time for everyone to upgrade.)

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question as to why the attribute is applied.